# systemd start a service only if another service runs without errors

Tags: systemd

How can I start a service unit only if another service unit runs without any errors?

I have 2 service units:

```
#echo-date-0.service
[Unit]
Description=

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/bash/echo-date-0.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target



#echo-date-1.service
[Unit]
Description=

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/bash/echo-date-1.sh
Requires=echo-date-0.service
After=echo-date-0.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have the script echo-date-0.sh returning exit code 1 (exit 1), and if I check the status of echo-date-0.service I see:

```
Active: failed (Result:exit-code) 
Process: (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

But, echo-date-1.service runs even though I have it Requiring echo-date-0.service. How can I stop echo-date-1.service from running, if echo-date-0.service fails?

Comment: I think you should use BindsTo instead of Requires.  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: is there a limit to how many services you can "chain" with `BindsTo=` ? I have 4 services which im trying to "chain" with `BindsTo=` and the last service does not start. The last service is the one that is enabled, which then starts all the other services. It is the same script as this is for testing. So I have echo-date-0-3. I have echo-date-3 enabled but it does not run. Only echo-date-0-2 run. If i start echo-date-3.service manually, it runs without errors.

Comment: Or how about this, can I start more than 1 service if a service runs successfully? Meaning, if echo-date-0.service runs and is a success, then start echo-date-1,2,3

Answer (score 4):

```
#echo-date-0.service
[Unit]
Description=

[Service]
Type=oneshot
## Stay alive for other services to acknowledge 
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/user/bash/echo-date-0.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target



#echo-date-1.service
[Unit]
Description=
Requires=echo-date-0.service
After=echo-date-0.service
## A unit that must be in an active non-erroring state
## and combos great with After=
BindsTo=echo-date-0.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/bash/echo-date-1.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[Jesse_b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/237982/jesse-b) was, at least for me, correct in mentioning `BindsTo=` within the [systemd.unix](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) would be useful.

And [Bigon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28791/bigon) is correct in stating that the `[Unit]` section should have `Requires=` & `After=`.

Effectively `echo-date-0.service`, in the above (and hopefully functioning) example, remains *alive* as a service (so running `systemctl stop echo-date-0.service` is required to reset state), but by setting things up so and combining `After=` & `BindsTo=` within `echo-date-1.service` pointing back to the service that must not error, this *should* achieve what the OP is asking for here.

One should be able to run `systemctl list-dependencies --before <service/trigger>` on `echo-date-0.service` in this case, to view services that linked to it in one form or another.

Answer (score 0):

`Requires=` and `After=` need to be in the `[Unit]` section